# Prove this matrix rotates a point in a plane by t radians

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations

I have seen in diferent math posts that the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}$$
rotates a point $p$ in the plane counterclockwise by an angle of $t$. I was wondering if someone could explain why this matrix works as it does.

---

I'm not even sure if this is correct, nor if it relates to the matrix I'm trying to understand, but this is what I have tried:

Suppose you want to rotate the point $p = (p_x,p_y)$ by an angle of $t$. Let's call this new point $q = (q_x,q_y)$.

$q_x = p_x cos (t) + p_x sin (t)$,

$q_y= p_y cos (t+π/2) + p_y sin(t+π/2)$

and we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}\ p_x cos (t)&\ p_x sin (t)\\\ p_y sin (t+π/2)&\ p_ycos (t+π/2)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}q_x \\q_y\end{pmatrix}$$

With $q_x + q_y = q$

---

Any thoughts/ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried visualizing this on a graph? Take a point on a graph $(x, y)$ and see what happens to it. Alternatively, take any point $(x, y)$ and see what you need to do to it to rotate it anticlockwise by some angle $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Way 1**

$$\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\implies \begin{cases}X=\cos(t)x-\sin(t) y\\Y=\sin(t)x+\cos(t)y\end{cases}.$$

Now, one can show that $$X^2+Y^2=x^2+y^2,$$ what mean that $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ belong to the same circle. Therefore, $(X,Y)$ is the image of $(x,y)$ by a rotation of center $(0,0)$. To find the angle, one can compute $$\frac{\left<\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}\right>}{\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\right\|\left\|\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}\right\|},$$
what gives the cosinus between $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}$ and conclude.

**Way 2**

If you know complex number, you can prove that $$X+iY=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{it}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t)),$$
and it allow you to conclude.

**Added**

$$\frac{\left<\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}\right>}{\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\right\|\left\|\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}\right\|}=\frac{\cos(t)x^2-xy\sin(t)+xy\sin(t)+\cos(t)y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\cos(t)=\cos(t).$$

Therefore the angle between $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ is $t$.

Comment: I really don't know much about math. In "Way 1" I understand everything up to $X^2+Y^2=x^2+y^2$, however, I don't know the meaning of that weird thing in those weird parenthesis, could you at least tell me how is it called so that I can google it? Thank for your answer by the way.

Comment: $\left<\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}y\\ y\end{pmatrix}\right>=Xx+Yy$ is the scalar product, and $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\end{pmatrix}\right\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the norm.

Comment: I'm truly sorry that I don't understand, but could you show the complete proof of "Way 1"?

Comment: @Leo : I edit my answer. But it's probably not the way you have to do if you don't know all those notion. Maybe a draw would be the best for you...